# Зачем в джейквери нужны итераторы each() и map()?

Tags: jquery

Привет.

Вопрос по джейквери. Зачем в джейквери нужны методы-итераторы *each()* и *map()*, которые пробегаются по всем *DOM*-объектам-узлам из выборки (выборка - это объект джейквери) и делают что-то (то, что задано в функции-параметре)? В джейквери и так полно специфических функций-методов (addClass(),css()...), каждый из которые пробегается по ВСЕМ объектам из выборки и что-то делает (добавляют/удаляют свойства стиля, классы, бегают по дереву DOM...), их возможностей, по идее, хватает, чтобы сделать ВСЕ, что хочешь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> по идее, хватает, чтобы сделать ВСЕ, что хочешь.

Нет, не хватает. Всегда есть специальные случаи, которые не предусмотрены во встроенных средствах.

Пример: из-за отсутствия метода *reduce* с помощью each можно выбирать часть значений подходящих по условию.

```
var positive = [];
$('selector').each(function(i,el){
    if(el.value > 0) positive.push({[i]:el});
});
```

---

Либо еще вариант - выполнить действие со сторонним объектом

```js
$('span').each(function(i, el) {
  $('#res').append(el.innerHTML ? `~${el.innerHTML}~` : 'empty');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>1</span>  <span>2</span>  <span></span>  <span>4</span>  <span></span>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Кроме того, не стоит забывать, что метод *each* может применяться не только к объектам jQuery, но и к обычным объектам, заменяя `for..in` и к массивам, унифицируя при этом доступ, не зависимо от типа коллекции.

К тому же, все перечисленные методы используют метод *`each`* внутри себя.

*`map`* - стоит несколько в стороне от всего этого, так как предназначена не для выполнения какой-то функции над элементами коллекции, а для **получения новой** коллекции на основе заданной.

Comment: то есть, первоначально был метод each , а потом понапридумывали кучу других частных методов (css,addClass...)?

Comment: "всегда есть специальные случаи, которые не предусмотрены во встроенных средствах" - можете привести простой пример?

Comment: @Dimon, добавил пример